# CSS3 polygons with images, how to?

Tags: css, svg, polygon, shapes, polygons

How can i do this shapes with image inside each block? Each block will have 100% width. Take a look at the example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5e9u.jpg

I have here the polygon, but how can i make it 100% of svg and with a full image background without losing aspect ratio?

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/acrr120/t9y950qy/`
```

Comment: you need to understand points (x,y) positions on UI to do custom shapes, refer to https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_polygon.asp for quick reference

Comment: I have done the polygon, but how can I make it full with? And with an image 100% without losing porportions?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your `svg` in a **container** and give the `height` you want and give also `overflow:hidden` by this way you will define the **height** you want and respecting the ratio for the **svg**

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="border:1px solid red">
      <polygon points="0,0 30,10 100,10 100,100 0,100" fill="red" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: And how can i make with a full image background without losing aspect ratio?